# Hiding Video Link (JW Player) From Source code

Tags: html, video, hide, jwplayer

```
    <div id="film">...</div>
<script>
jwplayer("film").setup({
    width:640,
    height:360,
    playlist: [{
        file: "https://videolink.mp4",
        image: "https://videopic.jpg",
        tracks: [{ 
            file: "http://video.srt", 
            label: "English",
            kind: "captions",
            "default": true 
        }]
}],
 captions: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: 10,
        backgroundOpacity: 50
    }
});</script>
```

I want to hide this code when users view with right click "Page source". How can I do it?

example 720pizle.com/izle/altyazi/american-sniper.html there is no embed code or video link in source code

Comment: You cannot. HTML code needs to be parsed by a browser and is human readable as well.

Comment: There are a lot of websites hiding their embed links

Comment: They are hiding them, but people can still get the source easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can't totally hide it, but you could use a tool to make it slightly more difficult to read for someone who isn't that technical. However, anyone with basic technical knowledge will be able to figure out the actual embed code using a developer tool (such as the Chrome dev tools, Firebug, etc).

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/encrypter.htm

That will make the code harder to read.

It isn't 100% secure though.

For instance, your code:

```
<div id="film">...</div>
<script>
jwplayer("film").setup({
    width:640,
    height:360,
    playlist: [{
        file: "https://videolink.mp4",
        image: "https://videopic.jpg",
        tracks: [{ 
            file: "http://video.srt", 
            label: "English",
            kind: "captions",
            "default": true 
        }]
}],
 captions: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: 10,
        backgroundOpacity: 50
    }
});</script>
```

Would turn into:

```
<script>
<!--
document.write(unescape("%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22film%22%3E...%3C/div%3E%0A%3Cscript%3E%0Ajwplayer%28%22film%22%29.setup%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A640%2C%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A360%2C%0A%20%20%20%20playlist%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20file%3A%20%22https%3A//videolink.mp4%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20image%3A%20%22https%3A//videopic.jpg%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tracks%3A%20%5B%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20file%3A%20%22http%3A//video.srt%22%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%22English%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20kind%3A%20%22captions%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22default%22%3A%20true%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%5D%2C%0A%20captions%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%27%23FFFFFF%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontSize%3A%2010%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20backgroundOpacity%3A%2050%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%29%3B%3C/script%3E"));
//-->
</script>
```

But someone could un encrypt it using a tool, or just use Firebug, etc, to see the actual output.

Comment: example http://720pizle.com/izle/altyazi/american-sniper.html there is no embed code in source code

Comment: I can see it using Firebug. It it being loaded inside of an iFrame. Also the entire player code is seen using Firebug: jwplayer('player').setup({
        file: '/player/oynat.asp?v=aHR0cHM6Ly9saDMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tL3E0VUNIdm9hQkVjdzE4a09KTHJUcmRfMURnWHEzTFo2Q2dhTnFsRk5Tdz1tMTg=',
        type: 'mp4',
  width: '100%',
  height: '90%',
        autostart: 'false',
  title: 'Plus Player (Flash)',
        fallback: 'false',
        primary: 'flash'
    });

Comment: I wanna do that. how can i do it

Comment: Put your player into an iframe, just like they are doing. Then use the tool from my answer above to encrypt the player setup code. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: could you give me an example code i'm using that jwplayer code and wp how should i change it? or is there a wp plugin for this?

Comment: There is no WP plugin for this. You can't do what you are trying to do using the WP plugin. And hiding the code, like I said, doesn't work, as I prove above.

Comment: could you give me an example iframe code for hiding mp4 link

Comment: im waiting your answer

Comment: please help me about this subject

Comment: I already gave you the answer above about how to encrypt the player embed code. Then you just have to put that into an iframe, which I posted a link about a few comments above. If you are trying to do this using our WordPress plugin, that is simply not possible to do, though, since the plugin doesn't use iFrames, or raw embed code.

Answer (score -1):

Yes It is possible. create session variable in php and try to run video code

Comment: html :
<?php 
 session_start();
 $_SESSION["videonm"] = $videoname;
?>
<video controls="" width="558" height="500"  autoplay="" name="media"><source src="http://localhost/path/video_test.php" type="video/mp4"></video>

Comment: CSS : 
<style>
video::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
display:none;
 }
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
overflow:hidden;}
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {width: calc(100% + 30px);}
</style>

Comment: video_test.php:
<?php 
 session_start();
$name= $_SESSION['videonm'];

$ctype= 'video/mp4';
                header('Content-Type: ' . $ctype);
                $file_path_name = "../path/path/path/".$name;
                $handle = fopen($file_path_name, "rb");
                $contents = fread($handle, filesize($file_path_name));
                fclose($handle);
echo $contents;
$_SESSION['videonm']="";
?>

Comment: My code given above. Its working 100%. If any one query then comment please.